# How to install png++ on windows platform

Tags: c++, windows, makefile, libpng

Now I cannot install png++ on windows platform because makefile cannot work properly in windows even though I have installed some makefile tools like GnuWin32. Is there a CMakeLists document to install png++? cause cmake works well in windows.

PS. I have referred to this [CMakeLists sample](https://fedetft.wordpress.com/2010/10/05/handling-png-images-in-cpp/) . But actually it can just read and write images but not install png++.

The error is as follows.

```
png++-0.2.9>make libpng-config="(previous path)\installed\LPNG1626\bin"
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, libpng-config --cflags, ...) failed.
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, libpng-config --ldflags, ...) failed.
make -C example libpng-config=(previous path)\\installed\\LPNG1626\\bin
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, libpng-config --cflags, ...) failed.
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, libpng-config --ldflags, ...) failed.
make[1]: Entering directory `..../png++-0.2.9/example'
g++     pixel_generator.cpp   -o pixel_generator
pixel_generator.cpp:35:19: fatal error: png.hpp: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make[1]: *** [pixel_generator] ′í?ó 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `..../png++-0.2.9/example'
make: *** [examples] ′í?ó 2
```

Comment: Would you mind sharing any full error messages you get?

Comment: Not an answer,and perhaps not helpful, but why install a png library when windows already ships with one?